# Mostrar imagenes de producto en el home laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy trabajando en una aplicacion para hacer cotizaciones. Uso Laravel 5.4 y necesito ayuda para saber ¿como hago para cargar la imagen de cada producto?
Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano

Este es el codigo de la vista home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">Productos</div>

<div class="panel-body">

<div class="row">
@foreach($articles as $article)
<div class="item col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
<div class="thumbnail">
<img class="group list-group-image" src="{{ $article->image }}" alt="" />
<div class="caption">
<h4 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">
{{$article->name}}</h4>
<p class="group inner list-group-item-text">
{{$article->part_number}}</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<p class="lead">
${{$article->price}}</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
<a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Añadir</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
<p>
{{ $articles->total() }} registros |
páginas {{ $articles->currentPage() }}
de {{ $articles->lastPage() }}
</p>


</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

[image: HomeProductos]

Comment: Las imagenes las estas almacenando en una carpeta dentro de tu proyecto.? y en la base de datos solo el nombre de la imagen.? avisame para ayudarte

Comment: Hola Oswuell, 
si, las imagenes estan en una carpeta del proyecto y en la base de datos, solo guardo la ruta

Campo image:
articles/August2017/MjuV4k236wzBepbrD8Oq.jpg

Ruta carpeta public/storage/articles/August2017

Desde ya gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. agrega esto:

```
<img src="{{ asset('ruta_completa'.$article->image) }}">
```

Me avisas si te sirve.

Saludos.

Comment: no me funciona. al inspeccionar la imagen, me reclama por
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php (line 179)

Comment: ahora siiiii,, en la ruta solo puse el "storage"
<img class="group list-group-image" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$article->image) }}" alt="" />

Me carga las imagenes, pero con distinto tamaño,, me imagino que se podrá ajustar con Css,, bueno,, ya me las arreglaré con eso..

Gracias @Oswuell

Comment: Si utiliza boostrap y llamas sus clases y listo. Saludos